# What is the string Format for alphabet in WPF?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, string-formatting, wpftoolkit

I want to write a `String.Forat` in alphabet can you please tell How to write it I know the pattern for currency but don't know the alphabet.  CanI write `StringFormat = "{}{A-Z,a-z}"` for alphabet?

```
    StringFormat="{}{0:C}"
```

I am doing validation.I want to enter only Alphabets in textBox need First letter Uppercase rest of lower letter .When i enter any numeric value then it show me a error,but use any WPF Validation,but i don't know how to do use the StringFormat for alphabets

Comment: We need to know what you plan to use `StringFormat` for.

Comment: Sounds like you want a regular expression not `StringFormat`

Comment: How can i use regular expression for this,I realy stuck in this...

Comment: Maybe you cannot. I suggest you to use IValueConverter approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyTextBox: TextBox
{
  public MyTextBox()
{
    this.PreviewTextInput += new TextCompositionEventHandler(TextBox_PreviewTextInput);
    this.AddHandler(DataObject.PastingEvent, new DataObjectPastingEventHandler(OnPaste));
}

private void OnPaste(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
{            
    if (e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(String)))
    {
        String text = (String)e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(String));
        if (!IsTextAllowed(text))
        {
            e.CancelCommand();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        e.CancelCommand();
    }
}

void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = !IsTextAllowed(e.Text);
}

private static bool IsTextAllowed(string text)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z]+$"); //regex that matches disallowed text
    return regex.IsMatch(text);
}
}
```

Use a customTextBox like above